# Занесение данных о печати в Excel

Tags: c#, windows

Как можно скопировать данные из стандартного приложения "Печать" о файле(страницы, автор файла)? Например, я печатаю Word документ(конечно в приоритете весь пакет Office) и хочу, чтобы когда я нажал напечать(допустим, что мое приложение, которое должно скопировать данные - находится в трее), после чего файл печатается, а мое приложение скопировало нужные данные и занесла их в таблицу Excel находящееся на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

В описании того, что вы хотите - много концептуальных проблем, вы не указали какие данные конкретно вы хотите, сказали только что из Word в Excel - а тут уже куча проблем. Т.к. Word это текст, причём сильно стилизованный, а Excel - это таблица, и в такие возможности она не может.
Если вам нужно в Excel вести лог - это одно, а если делать копию документов которые вы отправляете на печать - это другое.
В любом случае вам нужно перехватывать WinAPI вызов печати, смотреть что за программа его вызвала, и смотреть какой файл открыт в этом программе.
Так-же есть служба печати (spooler, или диспетчер печати)
И ещё есть каталог, куда отправляются задачи на печать: %systemroot%\System32\Spool\Printers\

Comment: Спасибо. Указал не совсем точно, но все же указал - данные, это автор файла и кол-во страниц печати

Comment: Автор файла из атрибутов файла? Или всё же имя пользователя, отправляющего задание печати? Если второе, то всё это должно быть в WinAPI диспетчера печати. Тут описание WinAPI функций для работы с диспетчером печати: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printing-and-print-spooler-functions Обратите внимание на функции EnumJobs и GetJob, возможно это именно то, что вам нужно. Так-же есть nuget пакет Vanara.PInvoke.Printing, который упростит вашу задачу. Подписки на события я не увидел, есть они или нет - не знаю, возможно нужно будет заводить таймер и смотреть очередь.